# LINQ .OrderBy creates nested casing

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to query the table and return the rows in specified custom order based on a status column.

It's a very straight forward `SQL` query:

```
SELECT  * From Table1
WHERE Id = 1
ORDER by CASE 
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status1' THEN 1
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status2' THEN 2
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status3' THEN 3
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status4' THEN 4
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status5' THEN 5
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status6' THEN 6
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status7' THEN 7
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status8' THEN 8
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status9' THEN 9
      WHEN [Status] = 'Satus10' THEN 10
      WHEN [Status] = 'Status11' THEN 11
      ELSE [Status] END ASC
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same query using `LINQ`.

```
var data = _myContext.Table1.Where(l => l.Id == 1).Select(lp =>
            new DataModel
            {
                Id = lp.Id,
                Status = lp.Status,
                ...
            })
            .OrderBy(l => 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status1.ToString() ? 1 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status2.ToString() ? 2 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status3.ToString() ? 3 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status4.ToString() ? 4 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status5.ToString() ? 5 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status6.ToString() ? 6 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status7.ToString() ? 7 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status8.ToString() ? 8 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status9.ToString() ? 9 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Status10.ToString() ? 10 : 
                       l.Status == StatusEnum.Sattus11.ToString() ? 11 : 0
            );
```

But this query fails with:

> Case expressions may only be nested to level 10.

Looking at the profiler, I see the EF creates the following query, which in return fails since I have more than 10 values specified:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [l].[Id],[l].[Status], ...
FROM [Table1] AS [l]
WHERE [l].[Id] = @__id_0
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_1
    THEN 1 ELSE CASE
        WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_2
        THEN 2 ELSE CASE
            WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_3
            THEN 3 ELSE CASE
                WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_4
                THEN 4 ELSE CASE
                    WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_5
                    THEN 5 ELSE CASE
                        WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_6
                        THEN 6 ELSE CASE
                            WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_7
                            THEN 7 ELSE CASE
                                WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_8
                                THEN 8 ELSE CASE
                                    WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_9
                                    THEN 9 ELSE CASE
                                        WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_10
                                        THEN 10 ELSE CASE
                                            WHEN [l].[Status] = @__ToString_11
                                            THEN 11 ELSE 0
                                        END
                                    END
                                END
                            END
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        END
    END
END',N'@__id_0 int,@__ToString_1 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_2 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_3 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_4 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_5 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_6 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_7 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_8 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_9 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_10 nvarchar(4000),@__ToString_11 nvarchar(4000)',@__id_0=1,@__ToString_1=N'Status1',@__ToString_2=N'Status2',@__ToString_3=N'Status3',@__ToString_4=N'Status4',@__ToString_5=N'Status5',@__ToString_6=N'Status6',@__ToString_7=N'Status7',@__ToString_8=N'Status8',@__ToString_9=N'Status9',@__ToString_10=N'Status10',@__ToString_11=N'Status11'
```

Is there a way to write this query, so it doesn't uses `ELSE CASE` and just matches the above `SQL` query?

I do have few options to bypass this. Write a stored procedure and get the output I need or store the query in a list without `OrderBy` and Order the list. But I'm currious to see if there's a way to do this in that query.

Comment: The SQL query works fine. It's the LINQ query needs to be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known current EF Core limitation, tracked by [#12729 Flatten CASE expressions to avoid error "Case expressions may only be nested to level 10"](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12729).

Unfortunately not scheduled to be addressed at all and no workaround provided. Also using value converter doesn't work.

Probably the best you could do is to create, map and use a [database scalar function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping).

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for the link to the issue.

Comment: I ended up using `context.Set<Customer>().FromSql($@"...")` from the link you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: It seems they are finally addressing this issue. In 3.1.4 it will be fixed. Yey!! https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12729

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to version 3.1.4 (not available yet, but it will be soon). This issue [has been fixed there](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12729).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not LINQ per say, but if you create a computed column that correspond to your CASE, you could sort by this column. You can use functions in a computed column and if that function is simple, the column can be stored and indexed.